# Trying to run a SQL query from a text box and display in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I've got the code below and am getting the error

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection vid = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\jlm\\Desktop\\Wk5ex01vbMills\\AdventureWorksDW_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       try 
          {         

           string str = TextBox1.Text;
           SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);

           vid.Open();
           xp.ExecuteNonQuery();

           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
           da.SelectCommand = xp;
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           da.Fill(ds);
           GridView1.DataSource = ds;
           GridView1.DataBind();
           vid.Close();
          }

       catch (Exception c)
          {
                Label1.Text = (c.Message);
          }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are u actually allowing to enter SQL statement for execution?

Comment: The entire sql statement should be entered into the text box, something like SELECT * FROM DimCustomer

Comment: What if someone enters `DELETE FROM DimCustomers` or `DROP Table DimCustomers` ?

Comment: Limiting things is next on my todo list, but I can't even get the search working.

Comment: Ok, that said I think you're missing second \ in `=(LocalDB)\v11.0` - should be `(localdb)\\v11.0`. Verify the rest of the connection string for validity

Comment: Jesus, so simple, i just didn't see it after looking forever. sorry to have bothered you guys. It works. I will now work on keeping people from screwing it up. Thanks

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, please post your comment as an answer so we can up vote and marked it answered.

Comment: @BlackFrog ok, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `\` in your connection string in a part `(LocalDB)\v11.0`. Should be `localdb)\\v11.0`.

That said - it's really risky to allow entering raw SQL to be executed against your DB. Even if you take all precautions not to allow dangerous commands - there's always a chance that something can slip thru.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\rinka.sai\\Desktop\\WebApplication1\\App_Data\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(TextBox1.Text,conn);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() ;
        GridView1.DataSource = sdr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        sdr.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```